# How to get tokens out of a metamask account

Tags: mist, tokens, metamask

I transferred tokens (GNT) from an exchange to a metamask account but I can't figure out how to get them out. They do not show up in metamask, but etherscan shows them. I tried to import the account to mist but I do not have a json file to import it, only the private key. I am not sure if metamask has the capability to transfer them? I also do not know how to create a json file or import that account to mist. Any direction greatly appreciated? learning slowly. Thanks!

Comment: Lots of posts about moving tokens but can't seem to find any information as to where to find the actual tokens. What number is the token ID? How many characters? Where on etherbase is it located. how can you "manage" your tokens without seeing them?

Answer (score 11):

Thanks for asking, this is a common question but did not have a good public answer. I've updated [the MetaMask user FAQ to include a response](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/USERS.md#managing-tokens), and am copying that answer here:

MetaMask does not currently display your token balances, but that doesn't mean you can't manage your tokens with MetaMask!

Since MetaMask allows any website to interact with the blockchain, you can use any token managing UI you like to view and send tokens.

A few popular options are:

- [The Ethereum Wallet](https://wallet.ethereum.org/)
- [Token Ninja](https://tokenninja.github.io)
- [Token Factory](https://tokenfactory.surge.sh/#/factory)
- [My Ether Wallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction)

Just visit any of these sites with MetaMask installed, and you'll be able to manage your tokens freely.

Comment: The current version of MetaMask (3.9.2) does now support the display of tokens directly within it.  In the account view go to the "tokens" tab, click the "+" button at the bottom and enter the address of the token's contract into the "Token Address" field for the token you're using.  In the case of Golem (GNT) that's 0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d.  MetaMask doesn't currently display how much that's worth (in ETH/USD/anything else) but at least it does let you keep track of your tokens without having to visit another website.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the private key you can use https://www.myetherwallet.com/ to transfer the tokens.

Comment: I do not believe *mywalletwallet.com* supports testnets. For people wish to interact with their tokens on testnets, MetaMask + Token Factory does the trick for me.