# Accessing ERC-20 tokens in MetaMask

Tags: tokens, metamask

I sent tokens (veri) from my ether wallet to meta mask address ether scan shows the transaction but i cannot see them or send them.
If you have a solution please explain as if i were 4 yr old.
cheers
james

Answer (score 3):

Currently MetaMask does not directly support ERC-20 tokens. However, you can use MetaMask with third party token management service.

Token management services include

- The Ethereum Wallet
- Token Ninja
- Token Factory

See [MetaMask FAQ of managing tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15266/how-to-get-tokens-out-of-a-metamask-account).

Alternatively, to have a user friendly interface to access the tokens, you can to export your private key from MetaMask and then import it in a token friendly standalone wallet.

[Please see for a full list of token friendly wallets.](https://tokenmarket.net/what-is/ethereum-token-wallets/)

Answer (score 3):

As of the time of writing, you can display your ERC20 tokens by clicking on "Tokens" -> "Add Token" and then adding the requested information on the form.

- Token address seems to be your wallet address.
- Check you address on etherscan to find your token symbols and Token Decimals. For example, here you can see that the token symbol for EOS happens to be EOS, and they have 18 decimals. https://etherscan.io/token/EOS?a=0xd94c9ff168dc6aebf9b6cc86deff54f3fb0afc33

You can find images and more detailed instructions here:
http://metamask.consensyssupport.happyfox.com/kb/article/4-managing-tokens

Answer (score 0):

Open your MetaMask.
Click on the top left button (menu)
Scroll down to see "Add Token"
Choose "custom token" (or whatever is the second possibility to "search")
In the Token Address put 0x0e3de3b0e3d617fd8d1d8088639ba877feb4d742 and the rest will fill up automatically.