# Transferred tokens to METAMASK address

Tags: metamask

Please bear with me for I am a newbie. I transferred my UTRUST tokens to my METAMASK account successfully. I can see the number of tokens using ETHERSCAN but it is still showing zero ETH on my METAMASK browser.

Can someone help to explain why is happening? Is it possible to rectify the problem by crediting the account with the value in ETH or redirect the tokens to another address?

Here are my addresses:

CONTRACT address:  0x70a72833d6bf7f508c8224ce59ea1ef3d0ea3a38

METAMASK address:  0x418722958BEA3B3e6411E7fA67d392a2FE410E2a

Comment: "is still showing zero ETH" Well, you don't have any ether in that account, so MetaMask (and Etherscan and any other tool you use) will correctly show a balance of 0. Were you expecting to have ether in that account? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a [duplicate](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15266/how-to-get-tokens-out-of-a-metamask-account). Take a look at a comment under the top answer:

> The current version of MetaMask (3.9.2) does now support the display of tokens directly within it. In the account view go to the "tokens" tab, click the "+" button at the bottom and enter the address of the token's contract into the "Token Address" field for the token you're using. In the case of Golem (GNT) that's 0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d. MetaMask doesn't currently display how much that's worth (in ETH/USD/anything else) but at least it does let you keep track of your tokens without having to visit another website.

In case of UTRUST you should enter this contract address:

> 0x70a72833d6bf7f508c8224ce59ea1ef3d0ea3a38

If you transferred UTRUST tokens to Metamask address you should expect to see there UTRUST tokens, not Ether.